# Need hidden input value to stay in form php

Tags: php

I have drop down in pop up window where users can choose their country. I am using hidden field to submit choice with php and when I hit "submit" button I get the country which was chosen. Information about country is shown in the header so it should be on every page but when I start to browse between pages the country value dissapeares. How can I keep it on every page?

```
<div class="field">
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php $_countries = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')->loadData()->toOptionArray(false); ?>
                <?php if (count($_countries) > 0): ?>
                    <select name="country" id="country" onchange="print(this.value)">
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <?php foreach($_countries as $_country): ?>
                            <?php if(!in_array($_country['value'], $arrNO)):?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>" >
                                    <?php echo $_country['label'] ?>
                                </option>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <input id="choice" type="hidden" name="fname" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
            </form>
            <div id="usWarning"><p><span class="red">NOTE</span>: If you live in <span class="red">Arizona</span>, <span class="red">Iowa</span>, <span class="red">Maryland</span>, <span class="red">Oklahoma</span>, <span class="red">South Dakota</span>, <span class="red">Vermont</span>, <span class="red">Washington</span> or <span class="red">Wisconsin</span>, we are unfortunately not allowed to sell tobacco to you. Its forbidden with online sales of tobacco in these states.</p></div>
        </div>
```

"Value" for the hidden input field assigned with the help of JS:

```
function print(value) {
    document.getElementById("choice").value=value;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are looking for `session` or `cookie`

Comment: use cookies or sessions to store the data(choice)

Comment: Problem with `session` that it expiers within 20 min, problem with `cookie` it doesn't save imideately when I hit submit button... :S

Answer (score 0):

You could make a **session** variable, to make the value persist across pages.

```
$_SESSION['countryname'] = "countryname";
```

**[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)**

**Edit:**

As you are using Sessions for a different purpose, set a cookie, separately, subject to **its own expiry**. using [**`setcookie`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Problem with session that it expiers within 20 min :S

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer It doesn't expire on its own, unless you make it do so explicity.

Comment: Yes, I know, I need session expire within 20 min

Comment: In that case, set a cookie, separately, subject to its own expiry. using [**`setcookie`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: I did `<?php setcookie('country_choice', $_POST["fname"], time()+3600);?>` but when I hit "submit" button it doesn't save it immideately, only if I navigate to other page and if I continue browsing cookie becomes empty :S

Answer (score 0):

To preserve a form value across requests as a hidden field simply means echoing it back into the form when rendering it.

```
<input id="choice" type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_POST ['fname']); ?>" />
```

Alternatively you can use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) to propagate the value to other pages.

Comment: Tried that didn't work because when I browse other pages on this website `$_POST["fname"]` becomes empty. Problem with session that it expiers within 20 min, problem with cookie it doesn't save imideately when I hit submit button... :S

Answer (score 0):

in action page

```
$_SESSION['country']    =   $_POST['country']
```

in form

```
<option value="<?php echo $_country['value'] ?>" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['country']) && $_SESSION['country']===$_country['value']) echo "selected"; ?>>
```

`echo` the session value(if set) to the hidden field too

Comment: Problem with session that it expiers within 20 min, problem with cookie it doesn't save imideately when I hit submit button... :S

Comment: I can't change the session time because I need it to expire within 20 min for other purpose.